# ImportError: cannot import name Multipoint

Tags: python-3.x, import, polygons, shapely

I'm trying to import Multipoint from shapely.geometry like so:

```
from shapely.geometry import Multipoint
state = Multipoint(((36.977397, -102.985840),(37.004892, -109.050293)(31.805382, -109.006348),(31.861385, -103.095703))).convex_hull

point.within(polygon)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Multipoint
```

Anyone know what's causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
```

Make sure you are using a capital 'P' in the word MultiPoint. [Docs](http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.geometry.html?highlight=multipoint#shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint)